# Windows server: applications running on the production server

Tags: windows-server-2003

How can some one determine what applications are running on a given server? This is a windows server. I think Windows 2000 server or may be newer. The applications could be .net applications or VB6 type of applications.

Comment: If you don't know even what the server is perhaps you should talk to your system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

[PsList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx) should do the job nicely.  I assume you're asking about checking the running processes on a server remotely.  If you're actually logged in to the server, [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will give you a lot more detail.